# Finding terms of a Taylor series where $f(x)$ is a function with a power

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I've been stuck with this Taylor series problem for a while now.

We have that $$ f(x) = (1 + x^2)^{-2/3} $$ and it's centered at $0$.

So what I thought of doing was the $$ \frac{f^{n}(a)(x - a)^{n}}{n!} $$ method of finding up to the 4th derivative then making a conjecture of the summation but the derivatives of that function get pretty complicated and take a while to compute.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Check generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: $$1-\frac{2 x^2}{3}+\frac{5 x^4}{9}-\frac{40 x^6}{81}+\frac{110 x^8}{243}-\frac{308 x^{10}}{729}+\frac{2618 x^{12}}{6561}-\frac{7480 x^{14}}{19683}+\frac{21505 x^{16}}{59049}-\frac{559130 x^18}{1594323}+\frac{1621477 x^20}{4782969}-\frac{4717024 x^22}{14348907}+\frac{41273960 x^{24}}{129140163}-\frac{120646960 x^{26}}{387420489}+\frac{353323240 x^{28}}{1162261467}-\frac{3109244512 x^{30}}{10460353203}+\frac{9133405754 x^{32}}{31381059609}+O(x^{33})$$ All the terms you need. About a=0. Credits to WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead, find the Taylor series for the function $$f(x)=(1+x)^{-{2\over 3}}$$ and then just plug in $x^2$ to the result.

Comment: I can't believe it's this simple. I always overcomplicate things! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The series can be obtained using the binomial theorem:
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(1+x^2\right)^{-2/3}\\
&={\large\sum_{\normalsize k=0}^{\normalsize\infty}}\binom{-2/3}{k}x^{2k}\\
&=1+\tfrac1{1!}\left(-\tfrac23\right)x^2+\tfrac1{2!}\left(-\tfrac23\right)\left(-\tfrac53\right)x^4+\tfrac1{3!}\left(-\tfrac23\right)\left(-\tfrac53\right)\left(-\tfrac83\right)x^6+\dots\\[6pt]
&=1-\frac23x^2+\frac59x^4-\frac{40}{81}x^6+\frac{110}{243}x^8-\frac{308}{729}x^{10}+\dots
\end{align}
$$